Getting error while adding custom fonts in React Native
I want to add custom fonts to my project in React Native
my App.js :

import React, { useState } from "react";
import { NavigationContainer } from "@react-navigation/native";
import { createStackNavigator } from "@react-navigation/stack";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";

const Stack = createStackNavigator();

const getFonts = () => {
  return Font.loadAsync({
    yekan: require("./app/assets/fonts/byekan.ttf"),
    ih: require("./app/assets/fonts/ih.ttf"),
  });
};

const App = () => {

  const[fontLoading, setFontLoading] = useState(false);

  if(fontLoading) {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator>
          <Stack.Screen name="Welcome" component={() => {}} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }else{
    return (
      <AppLoading 
        startAsync={getFonts}
        onFinish={() => setFontLoading(true)}
      />
    )
  }
};

export default App;


but I got this error :
Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

I can use useFonts hook to add my custom fonts but now I need to use Font.loadAsync in my project
can anyone help me with this?

You must pass a React component in component prop in Stack.Screen.
